# What is the use of *this in combine function given below

Tags: c++, c++11

```cpp
Sales_data& Sales_data::combine(const Sales_data &rhs)
{
    units_sold += rhs.units_sold; // add the members of rhs into
    revenue += rhs.revenue; // the members of ''this'' object
    return *this; // return the object on which the function was called
}
```

I saw above method somewhere, and I am confused why `*this` pointer is being returned? Even though without it (using `void` return type) function does the same thing. I know how `*this` pointer works but I was confused why `*this` pointer was used in above context.

I am not an expert in C++, so can any one explain what am I missing?

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to search and then research and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*` operator is just dereferencing the address of the this-pointer. This way you get the desired return type, which is a reference to your `Sales_data` class. An educated guess would be that the implentation is this way to chain function calls, e.g. by `a.combine(b).combine(c).combine(d);` etc.

With the `void` interface you were referring to you would have to write:

```
a.combine(b);
a.combine(c);
a.combine(d);
```

I would say in the end it is personal preference whether you go for one or the other implementation.

Comment: Historical footnote, `this` is a pointer to the object rather than a reference to the object because `this` was introduced very early in the language, and references were added several years later.

Answer (score 5):

It allows method chaining, e.g. if you have multiple sales data objects that you want to combine, you can write

```
all_data.combine(alices_data).combine(charlies_data).combine(bobs_data);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer,
so alices_data will combine first, then charlies_data and then bobs_data right?

Comment: Exactly, alices_data will combine first, then charlies_data and then bobs_data.

Comment: And for a more concise explanation of _why_ it's evaluated in that order, see the table and its description in [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and note that the operator associativity for [member access](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators) is left-to-right.